# how to write test class for below apex class?

Tags: apex, unit-test

I have created a code to get picklistfield dynamically and its values...
now i want to create test class for it i have created test class but its seems wrong...
Please help to create test class for belo apex class...

Apex class:

```
public with sharing class OppSt {

public List<string> Opp{get;set;}

public static list<string> oppstm(){
    list<string> Opp = new list<string>();
    Schema.DescribeFieldResult fieldResult = Opportunity.StageName.getDescribe();
    SObjectType accountType = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get('Opportunity');
    Map<String,Schema.SObjectField> mfields = accountType.getDescribe().fields.getMap();

    List<Schema.PicklistEntry> ple = fieldResult.getPicklistValues();
    for( Schema.PicklistEntry f : ple)
    {
        Opp.add(f.getLabel());
    } 
    system.debug('============='+Opp); 
    return Opp;  
}

}
```

Test class:

```
  @isTest
  private class TestOpportunityStageUtility {

static testMethod void myUnitTest() {

    Opportunity o = new Opportunity ();
    o.StageName = 'abc';
    insert o;
  } 

}
```

Comment: Triggers - that respond to inserts, updates etc - can be made to run by code such as your test. Other Apex code - utility classes, controllers - need to be explicitly invoked from the test class as highfive shows.

Answer (score 3):

you are doing all but one step behind. In your test class, call your Apex class method.

```
static testMethod void myUnitTest() {
   // Your code
   List<string> testStringList = OppSt.oppstm();

   // Add some assertEquals as per your logic to test the method
}
```